# Different template class realizations but same member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization, class-template

I have a template matrix class with some typical member functions such as `inverse`, `determinant`, `operator*`, etc.. And I want to reuse the code for these member functions in template realizations for both *fixed*- and *dynamic* size matrices.
**Is this possible? and if yes, how?**

In the code below, like Eigen, I use "`-1`" for dynamic dimensions. Yes I know I could use a library for this, but for my application, that is not feasible. *The standard functionality is not possible due to the nature of the application (CUDA)*

**Is it possible to make a template class with different member variable size depending on the template parameters?** For instance when `Dynamic_Rows = -1` and `Dynamic_Cols = -1`, then the data is just `T **data`, but otherwise its `T data[Rows][Cols]`.

As of now, I have one template class for dynamic size matrices ("*minimal*" example below, note that the code is subject to errors/mistakes because I am relatively fresh in "advanced" class templating).

But I want to have a fixed size data member variable in the case of a fixed size matrix instantiation.

```
template<class T, int Dynamic_Rows, int Dynamic_Cols>
class CMatrix<T, -1, -1>
{
private:
   size_t n_rows, n_cols;
   T** data;

   void allocate_data();
   void deallocate_data();

public:
   CMatrix(const size_t n_rows, const size_t n_cols);
   CMatrix(const CMatrix& other);
   ~CMatrix();
   CMatrix& operator=(const CMatrix& rhs);
   CMatrix exp() const;
};
```

with for instance the code for the `exp()` function below as

```
template <class T, int Dynamic_Rows, int Dynamic_Cols>
CMatrix<T, -1, -1> CMatrix<T, -1, -1>::exp() const
{
   CMatrix<T, -1, -1> result(n_rows, n_cols);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < n_rows; i++)
   {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < n_cols; j++)
      {
         result.data[i][j] = exp(result.data[i][j]);
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

The only thing I can think of now to allow for both dynamic and fixed-size matrices is to basically implement another template of the class as

```
template<class T, size_t Rows, size_t Cols>
class CMatrix<T, Rows, Cols>
{
private:
   size_t n_rows = Rows, n_cols = Cols;
   T data[Rows][Cols];

public:
   CMatrix() {}
   CMatrix(const CMatrix& other);
   CMatrix& operator=(const CMatrix& rhs);
   CMatrix exp() const;
};
```

using a variadic template

```
template<class T, int...> class CMatrix;
```

but then that would just duplicate the code for most of my member functions!

Comment: I would split Matrix class in Data part (where you handle data in dynamic or static form), and the "logical" part, (where you operator on `data[x][y]` regardless if it is dynamic or static).

Comment: If you get duplicated member functions, extract them to a common base class. This is a good case for CRTP (the code that manipulates `data` is the dame, but the type of `data` is different). However you should know that `T** data` is bad for performance. If performance is important, you want to use a one-dimensional array, and do the 2D address translation yourself.

Comment: @n.'pronouns' m I am not very familiar with CRTP, so do not see an immediate solution on how to use this here. Care to clarify with a short answer? Does the base class then have access to the data (either fixed or dynamic) for use in the functions? And yes I will go from double to single pointer for better performance, this is just an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very generic way to do such specializations using CRTP. It doesn;t require that there is a simple single condition that can be used to select an implementation of a data member, and leave the rest unchanged.

```
template <class T, class Impl> class MatrixBase {

   // data is NOT defined here
   Impl exp() const
   {
        Impl& self = static_cast<Impl&>(*this);             // <-- this is magic
        Impl result = self;                                 // <-- this is magic
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n_rows; i++)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < n_cols; j++)
            {
                result.data[i][j] = exp(result.data[i][j]); // <-- data is defined in Impl
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    // other functions that do not depend on actual type of data
};

template <class T>
class DynamicMatrix : public MatrixBase<T, DynamicMatrix<T>> {
    T** data;
    // define constructors etc here
};

template <class T, int Rows, int Cols>
class StaticMatrix : public MatrixBase<T, StaticMatrix<T, Rows, Cols>> {
    T[Rows][Cols] data;
    // define constructors etc here
};
```

Now that you have both `StaticMatrix` and `DynamicMatrix`, you can unify them into a single alias template if you wish.

```
template <class T, int Rows, int Cols>
using CMatrix = std::conditional_t <(Rows >= 0 && Cols >= 0),
                                     StaticMatrix<T, Rows, Cols>,
                                     DynamicMatrix<T>
                                   >;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a suitable solution for me. However, can you clarify the "magic" lines of code? Is that basically a run-time fetch of the derived class data into the suitable type Impl? I would then need to perform those magic lines of code in each function to fetch the data?  And is not static_cast a part of the std library, such that I would need a custom implementation?

Comment: The "magic" is lifting the *type* of `this` to that of a derived class that has `data` member. It has no run-time costs. It is OK because `MatrixBase` is designed to be used as a CRTP base class, so it knows it is derived from `Impl`.

Comment: @A_Man `static_cast` can be replaced by a c-style cast. *I would then need to perform those magic lines of code in each function to fetch the data* - either that, or write the first line once in an inline getter.

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m Follow-up question: Lets say the member function in MatrixBase is dependent on the type of Impl for its functionality. The solution would then be to define the function separately in the Derived classes instead? For instance if one needs to create a temporary Impl result(n_rows, n_cols), this is not possible for the StaticMatrix case because the Impl is then at compile-time defined as a StaticMatrix of a given <class T, int Rows, int Cols>, which may not correspond to n_rows and n_cols.

Comment: @A_Man you just create a DynamicMatrix in there and not an Impl. You only create Impl when you need it to be the same type as the current object.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible....[...] ...when `Dynamic_Rows = -1` and `Dynamic_Cols = -1`, then the data is just `T **data`, but otherwise its `T data[Rows][Cols]`?

You can provide a trait type whose specializations gives you the proper type for the `CMatrix`

```
template<typename T, int Rows, int Cols> struct type_helper final {
    static_assert(Rows >= 0 && Cols >= 0, "Rows and COls must be valid!");
    using type = T[Rows][Cols];
};

template<typename T> struct type_helper<T, -1, -1>  final {
    using type = T**;
};
```

Now in the class

```
template<class T, int Dynamic_Rows = -1, int Dynamic_Cols = -1>
class CMatrix /* final */
{
    // get the member Type like this!
    using Type = typename type_helper<T, Dynamic_Rows, Dynamic_Cols>::type;

    Type data;
public:

};
```

**([See a  demo online](https://godbolt.org/z/f97M7x))**

Comment: Neat! I will consider using this version, as it does not require much alteration.

Comment: @A_Man Yes.. That is a plus. Also note that, in case you keep only one `CMatrix`, always need to consider the change in code for both types in mem functions. In C++17 you could check the `Type` at compile time using `if constexpr` and the code under false statement can be discarded, again you will have one member function managing two different types. Compiler prior to C++17, you might need to use however SFINAE or specialization of `CMatrix`.

Comment: I would prefer to specialize the different part, as there are several places (constructor/destructor, possibly basic accessor) which need to branch, especially constructor and initializer list member initialization where `if constexpr` cannot be directly used (there is still lambda as workaround).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std::conditional_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) to select one type or another based on some compile-time constant, without duplicating the class.

However - I did something very similar once, and found that using a fixed size data structure (`std::array` instead of `std::vector`) gives little to no improvement in practical use cases.
A very big advantage of fixed size arrays (`std::array` or `type[fixed_size]`) is that the compiler is able to optimize out a lot of operations, but if the arrays are large the benefit can become negligible.

Also, you should consider *n. 'pronouns' m.*'s comment - especially if you're using a GPU (they tend to require data structures that are continuous in memory). Instead of using `T** data`, use a single `std::vector<T>`, and an additional `std::array<size_t, number_of_dimensions>` for size in each dimension. Then you can translate indices with something like this:

```
using Indices = std::array<size_t, number_of_dimensions>;

template <unsigned int n = number_of_dimensions>
static inline size_t indices_to_offset(Indices const & indices,
                                       Indices const & dimensions){
    if constexpr (n == 0) return 0;
    else {
        size_t const next_index_number = indices[n-1];
        assert(next_index_number < dimensions[n-1]);
        return next_index_number +
            dimensions[n-1]*indices_to_offset<n-1>(indices, dimensions);
    }
}

template <unsigned int n = number_of_dimensions>
static inline Indices offset_to_indices(size_t const offset,
                                        Indices const & dimensions,
                                        Indices indices = Indices()){
    if constexpr (n == 0) return indices;
    else {
        size_t const fast_dimension_size = dimensions[n-1];
        indices[n-1] = offset % fast_dimension_size;
        return offset_to_indices<n-1>(offset/fast_dimension_size , dimensions, indices);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will definitely go from double- to single pointer for performance gain.  Forgot to mention, but I cannot use std:: or std library functionality in general because this code is supposed to run on the GPU, hence why I even bother doing this.

Comment: Without the standard library your best bet is to implement contidional_t yourself (see *JeJo*'s answer). However, as I mentioned, my advice is not to bother with it at all. Once you have an implementation with a dynamic array you can try switching to fixed-size and see if you get any improvement in running time. See [this](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)

Comment: @JeJo The specific use I thought about is `std::conditional_t<Dynamic_Rows > 0, std::array<T, Dynamic_Rows>, std::vector<T> >`, possibly nested within another `std::conditional_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Turning my comment into answer (using `Vector` instead of `Matrix`):

split your class, so you have the part to specialize in a specific class, and the common part, something like:

```
// helper to allow variadic constructor without pitfall.
constexpr struct in_place_t{} in_place{};

template <typename T, std::size_t DIM>
class VectorData
{
protected: // You might even make it private and give the common accessor in public part
           // To avoid to use interface not shared with std::vector
    std::array<T, DIM> data;
public:
    VectorData() = default;

    template <typename ... Ts>
    VectorData(in_place_t, Ts&&... args) : data{std::forward<Ts>(args)...} {}
};

template <typename T>
class VectorData<T, std::size_t(-1)>
{
protected: // You might even make it private and give the common accessor in public part
           // To avoid to use interface not shared with std::array
    std::vector<T> data;
public:
    explicit VectorData(std::size_t size) : data(size) {}

    template <typename ... Ts>
    VectorData(in_place_t, Ts&&... args) : data{std::forward<Ts>(args)...} {}
};
```

Then the common part:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t DIM = std::size_t(-1)>
class Vector : public VectorData<T, DIM>
{
public:
    using VectorData<T, DIM>::VectorData;

    Vector(std::initializer_list<T> ini) : VectorData<T, DIM>(in_place, ini) {}

#if 1 // Those might go in `VectorData` to avoid to use `data` directly
    std::size_t size() const { return this->data.size(); }
    T& operator[](std::size_t i) { return this->data[i]; }
    const T& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return this->data[i]; }
#endif

    // Example of methods which don't care underlying container
    template <std::size_t DIM2>
    Vector& operator += (const Vector<T, DIM2>& rhs) {
        assert(this->size() == rhs.size());
        
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i != this->size(); ++i) {
            (*this)[i] += rhs[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template <std::size_t DIM2>
    friend Vector operator + (Vector lhs, const Vector<T, DIM2>& rhs) {
        return lhs += rhs;
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d86f07e254e71fee)